# Is there a way to check if one terraform module exists from another terraform module in the same project and set a variable that checks this?

Tags: terraform

In some of my projects I will include a terraform module named `gabrielle`. In some projects I will not include the terraform module `gabrielle`.

I have another terraform module called `s3-bucket` that will live in the same project that the `gabrielle` module could also live in. I want a variable in the `s3-bucket` terraform module to be set to true or false depending on if the `gabrielle` module is also in the same project (true if it is there and false if not).

Lets call my boolean variable that will be in the s3-bucket module `gabrielle_enabled`

In other-words - from the terraform `s3-bucket` module I want to check if the terraform `gabrielle` module is present in the same project and if so set a bool in the `s3-bucket` module to true.

Sounds relatively easy but so far I do not see how.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the object representing one module into another module:

```
module "gabrielle" {
  source = "./modules/gabrielle"

  # ...
}

module "s3-bucket" {
  source = "./modules/s3-bucket"

  gabrielle = modules.gabrielle
  # ...
}
```

Inside `./modules/s3-bucket` you would declare this variable as having an object type with whatever attributes of `gabrielle` are important to the behavior of `s3-bucket`:

```
variable "gabrielle" {
  type = object({
    # If the gabrielle module has an output value
    # named "example" which you'll use inside
    # s3-bucket, you can declare an attribute for
    # it like this.
    example = string
  })
  default = null
}
```

I intentionally declared this variable as `default = null` because that then makes it optional to specify in the `module "s3-bucket"` block, and if it's not specified then its value will be null.

You could then declare a local value inside the `s3-bucket` module which is `true` when a `gabrielle` object is provider:

```
locals {
  using_gabrielle = var.gabrielle != null
}
```

Elsewhere in the module you can use `local.using_gabrielle` to make decisions based on whether that object was passed in or not.